How to prevent shadow's Z-order changing?
I need to show popup window with my shadow drawing.
But I got interested thing: when I call popup of the window, which draw my own shadow in Dialog mode (popup form is topmost and modal), then I clicking on the main form (outside of popup modal form), then the shadow is hiding for main window (normal modal window is blinking in this case). If I will shith to other process in Windows and then switch to my running program, then shadow is refreshing and looks as it should. The question: how to prevent shadow hiding under main form?
The code:
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Windows.Forms;
    
    namespace TestShadow
    {
        public partial class Form1 : Form
        {
            public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }
            private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                PopupForm popupForm = new PopupForm();
                popupForm.ShowInTaskbar = false;
                popupForm.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
                popupForm.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
                StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
                var topLeft = button1.PointToScreen(new Point(0, 0));
                popupForm.Location = new Point(topLeft.X, topLeft.Y + button1.Height);
                popupForm.ShowDialog();
            }
        }
        public class PopupForm : Form
        {
            const int WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW = 0x00000080;
            protected override CreateParams CreateParams
            {
                get
                {
                    const int CS_NOCLOSE = 0x200;
                    const int CS_DROPSHADOW = 0x20000;
                    CreateParams cp = base.CreateParams;
                    cp.ClassStyle |= CS_NOCLOSE;
                    cp.ClassStyle |= CS_DROPSHADOW;
                    return cp;
                }
            }
        }
    }

The pictures:



p/invoke DwmXXX functions instead.  Example

If you override WndProc, trap WM_NCACTIVATE and call SetWindowPos() each time m.WParam == IntPtr.Zero, the window is redrawn with all its class styles. Eg., SetWindowPos(Handle, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3); - If you call the same function right after, but with the second parameter set to -2, you also make it flicker as a modal window should (you may want to ignore m.WParam in this case)

See also: Borderless Form Dropshadow, using DWM -- The rendering Policy and Attribute must be set after the Window has created its Handle. There, it's set in the OnHandleCreated() override

@Jimi thank you very much! I did: protected override void WndProc(ref Message m) { switch (m.Msg) { case WM_NCACTIVATE: SetWindowPos(Handle, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3); break; default: break; } base.WndProc(ref m); } and it works! But I not understand completelly about flickering when I click not on the modal window. Can you show code? Thanks!
